# Login to created Windows instance using Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am creating a Windows instance using Ansible. Once the instance got created I need to install IIS on that created instance automatically.

How to login to the newly created instance automatically?

What are the parameters I need to mention in the host (inventory) file to login?

Answer (score 0):

To connect to ec2 instances you will first need to retrieve the password using the `ec2_win_password` [module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/ec2_win_password_module.html)

Example:

```
    - ec2_win_password:
        instance_id: i-xxxxxxx
        region: us-west-2
        key_file: "/.ssh/yourPEM.pem"
        aws_access_key: "{{ aws_access_key }}"
        aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_secret_key}}"
        security_token: "{{ session_token }}"
        key_passphrase: "1122355"
      register: result
    - debug : msg="{{ result }}"
```

The result can be used as your `ansible_password`